# Is there something wrong with this explanation of Chebyshev's Inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

So I was revising (more like re-learning coz I suck) Chebyshev's Inequality using [this document](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Em20x18/markov). Specifically, I am referring to Example $7$ on Page $3$, which I shall reproduce below.

---

**Question**

A coin is weighted so that the probability of landing on heads is $0.2$. Suppose the coin is flipped $20$ times. Using Chebyshev's Inequality, find a bound for the probability it lands on heads at least $16$ times.

**Answer**

\begin{align}
P(X \geq 16) & =
P(0 \leq X \leq 16)
\\[5 mm] & =
P(-8 \leq X \leq 16)
\\[5 mm] & =
P(|X - 4| \geq 12)
\\[5 mm] & \leq
\frac {Var(X)} {12^2}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac {(20)(0.2)(0.8)} {144}
\\[5 mm] & =
\frac 1 {45}
\end{align}

---

I understand if we skip the first jump from $P(X \geq 16)$ to $P(|X - 4| \geq 12)$ because, as suggested in the document, $X \geq 0$. However, what I cannot get is how the first equality makes sense. In particular, how does $P(X \geq 16)$ equal $P(0 \leq X \leq 16)$? Also, how does $P(-8 \leq X \leq 16)$ equal $P(|X - 4| \geq 12)$?

I know the answer is correct but I cannot help but feel that the proof is not entirely mathematically right. Anyone who can explain why the first $3$ equalities make sense please do tell.

Comment: In the first line, shouldn't it be $1-P(0<X<16)$?

Comment: @Alex that's what I thought, but that's not what is written in the document. What's written in the document is what I typed. So I'm correct and the document is wrong, right?

Comment: The document would be better if it started $P(X \geq 16)  = 1 -
P(0 \leq X \lt 16) = 1-P(-8 \lt X \lt 16)  = P(|X - 4| \geq 12)$

Comment: @Henry Yes, exactly what I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be
$$
P(X>16)=P(X-4>12) < P(|X-4|>12)<\frac{20 \cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.8}{12^2}
$$
This is because $|x|>x$ always

Comment: Yes. This is what I was thinking too. Basically I feel that the proof would be correct if they had skipped the first $2$ inequalities and went from $P(X > 16)$ to $P(|X - 4| > 12)$ and the rest of the steps have no issue. But I just cannot wrap my head around the first $2$ inequalities.

Comment: It would be the case if $P(0\leq X \leq 16)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: But that was specified nowhere in the example, was it?

Comment: Since you have $n,p,q$, you can check it yourself: $\sum_{k=16}^{20}\binom{20}{k}p^k q^{20-k}$

Comment: @Alex: that second expression  would be about $0.000000014$ which is indeed less than$ \frac1{45} \approx 0.022$

Comment: @Alex what do you mean by $|x|>x$ always? I mean if $x$ is positive, then $|x|=x$?